# Specific Html tags validation with Standard .Net library

Tags: c#, regex

I've written a simple function to validate user input. Validation rule is to fail the validation if input contains (script or iframe) html tags only, otherwise it should succeed. Function is working fine. 
Do we've any library in .Net(Nuget package or something) that can provide the same functionality so i don't need to write regex to check specific html tags? 
My implementation using regex:

```
public static Regex regexes = new Regex("(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<iframe(.+?)\\</iframe\\>)");

protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    string str = (string)value;

    if (str != null)
    {
        if (regexes.IsMatch(str)) {                 
            return new ValidationResult($"A potentially dangerous value was detected from request {validationContext.Name}: {str}");
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, But my input would only contain strings like "<script>hello world</script>" or "hello world".

Comment: Is this a formal html document ?

Comment: @zubairm if it's an html document (with no errors) then an HTML parser is best to use.

Comment: The exact regex that will validate the form for these two : `<(?:(?:(script|iframe)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))>`

Comment: @ctwheels input is like in this format
"<script>hello world</script>" or "hello world".

Comment: Also, there is no need to escape angle brackets `<>` in regex. On some engines `\>` and `\<` are end/begin of word (boundary's).

Comment: [Mandatory reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3276027)

Comment: Thanks everyone, Just an fyi, I ended up using "HtmlAgilityPack"